# A msi to do File Operations in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, wix, windows-installer

We have a windows service which will connect to ftp server and do perform actions using command xml file. Actions like start/stop service, file copy and file replace using c#.

As we know when we working with file operation, we have to take care of backing up existing file and replacing when action fails, instead of doing all these using c# code, we thought of implementing an windows installer for file operations.

we know windows installer has best features and can easily executable using c# command.

Does anyone have idea about how to build or develop an msi for file operations ?

Edit :
For people who gave minus votes, please do check my answer.

Comment: Did you tried or found something so far ?

Comment: I'm trying with wix Richard .. Not so successful but trying. Let you know if I have positive results

Comment: WiX in general is relatively complex to set up but file copy is something relatively straight forward to do... What about http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html for example for local copy ? If the tricky part is in the "distant" copy what about using external commands ? (dont know if wix has integrated ftp features)

Comment: I've an Windows service which will connects to FTP server and do actions based on xml file. I will pass an msi which will be generated using an .wxs file in Visual Studio and then run silently. 

Is it sounding awkwardly ? do you have any suggestions ??

Comment: Describe this in the question, it's very important if you want help. It will also allow to reduce downvotes ;)

Comment: It's like buying Visual Studio Premium edition to edit text files only. Yes, you can do that, but it wasn't made for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've created msi using wix command line utility and then installed msi silently.

heat.exe dir "dirPath" -cg NewDemoGroup -g1 -gg -sf -srd -scom -sreg  -out "fragment.wxs"

> Harvests file and creates .wxs file

candle.exe product.wxs fragment.wxs -ext WixUIExtension

> creates .wixobj file

light.exe -out demo.msi -b "dirPath"   product.wixobj fragment.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension

> generates msi

and refer this link [Silent installation using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203300/silent-installation-using-c-sharp) to install silently msi ..