# I can't hide my process WPF

Tags: c#, installation

Finally give up on this, How can I hide this process.

Basically I want to do background  Installation. It did't ask for next and all. I just don't want that installation screen what should I do. Thank you

```
void _bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\AlisInstallerDemo\AlisEmail.exe";

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        MessageBox.Show("File Already Install ");
    else
    {
        //Install software
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/qb /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", @"C:\Users\d.soni\Desktop\setup.msi");
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silent installation using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203300/silent-installation-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly requesting a window with /qb. Run "msiexec /?" to see command line options. Perhaps you want "/qn" and "/quiet".

Comment: If the answer is correct, please mark it as an answer appropriately. (Click the checkmark)